# Jquery drag drop revert to original position and div on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have drag-and-drop items, intended to be dragged from one `div` and dropped into another `div`. I capture the original position of each item in hidden fields when they are created.

I want to get the items to go back to the original `div` and location on `dblclick`, but they always relocate inside the drop target `div`.

Any ideas?

```
<div id="cardPiles">
  <div id="D1" class="draggable" ondblclick="rev(this)">1</div>
  <div id="D2" class="draggable" ondblclick="rev(this)">2</div>
  <div id="D3" class="draggable" ondblclick="rev(this)">3</div>
  <div id="D4" class="draggable" ondblclick="rev(this)">4</div>
  <div id="D5" class="draggable" ondblclick="rev(this)">5</div>
  <div id="D6" class="draggable" ondblclick="rev(this)">6</div> 
</div>
```

```
function rev(me) {
  var b = $(me).text();
  var h = $('#H' + b).text();
  var s = h.split(',');
  var top = s[0];
  var left =s[1];
  $(me).parent().css({ position: 'relative' });  //tried absolute also
  $(me).css({top:top,left:left,position:'absolute' });
}
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Try `function rev(me) {
  $(me).removeAttr('style');
}`

Comment: Personally, I would store the origin details in a `data` attribute for each `div`. This way it travels with the object.

Comment: I am assuming you want the original to then reside in the new DIV until it is double clicked, and then you want it to snap back to it's original position?

Comment: FYI - I have a fiddle going for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u1rd9dpg/

Comment: Twisty - great response thanx. data attribute is a better idea. What I require is, in your fiddle example, when orange div (#cardpiles) elements are dropped onto blue div (#carddrop), dblclick on dropped element/s in blue div should send them back to the orange div to the same posn they originated from. Your example is similar to what I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible answer. If it does not fit your use case, edit your post with more details.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u1rd9dpg/6/

**HTML**

```
<div id="cardPiles">
  <div id="D1" class="draggable ui-widget-content" data-origin="">1</div>
  <div id="D2" class="draggable ui-widget-content" data-origin="">2</div>
  <div id="D3" class="draggable ui-widget-content" data-origin="">3</div>
  <div id="D4" class="draggable ui-widget-content" data-origin="">4</div>
  <div id="D5" class="draggable ui-widget-content" data-origin="">5</div>
  <div id="D6" class="draggable ui-widget-content" data-origin="">6</div>
</div>
<div id="cardDrop">
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function rev(me) {
  console.log("DoubleClick Detected.");
  var pos = me.data("origin");
  console.log("Returning to: ", pos);
  var $o = me.clone();
  $o.draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    start: log
  });
  me.remove();
  if ($("#cardPiles div").length == 0) {
    $("#cardPiles").append($o);
    return true;
  }
  $("#cardPiles .draggable").each(function(k, v) {
    var txt = parseInt($(v).text());
    if ($o.data("order") < txt) {
      $(v).before($o);
      return false;
    } else {
      $("#cardPiles").append($o);
    }
  });

}

function log(e, ui) {
  var pos = ui.offset;
  var $ob = $("#" + ui.helper.attr("id"));
  pos.order = parseInt(ui.helper.text());
  $ob.attr("data-top", pos.top);
  $ob.attr("data-left", pos.left);
  $ob.attr("data-order", pos.order);
  $ob.attr("data-origin", [pos.top, pos.left, pos.order].join(","));
  console.log("DragStart Position: ", pos);
  console.log("Logged: " + [$ob.data("top"), $ob.data("left"), $ob.data("order")].join(","));
}

$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    start: log
  });
  $("#cardDrop").on("dblclick", ".dropped", function() {
    console.log("Origin found: ", $(this).data("origin"), $(this).data("top"));
    rev($(this));
  });
  $("#cardDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#cardPiles div",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      var $drop = ui.draggable.clone();
      console.log("Dropped. Origin: ", $drop.data("origin"));
      $drop.removeAttr("style");
      $drop.addClass("dropped");
      $(this).append($drop);
      ui.draggable.remove();
      var c = $("#cardDrop div").length;
    }
  }).sortable({
    revert: true
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if you need to do this in CSS or not, but I went based on the order and let the CSS just define how they appear in the list.

When the `drag` starts, I log the origin details to various data attributes. This allows them to be retrieved later when there is an interaction with just that element.

When `drop` happens, I clone the original and then append the clone. Do not have to do this, yet for me, it helps me identify whats happening. Since it's no longer `draggable`, you could remove the class, but I just added `dropped` to be able to more easily catch the Double Click event.

When `dblclick` fires on our object, I clone it again, and re-append it back. Make it `.draggable()` again too. I hunt for the next item's number and fit it in underneath.

If the text within is not easy to order like that, I would add an `order` attribute or populate the `data-order` attribute. You can do this when it's dragged or read it from the ID... not sure what might work best for you.

You can do this over and over and drag all of them out of `#cardPile` if you like.

Comment: Just saw your updated fiddle example. Exactly what I required, Great Job!!

Comment: Twisty, when the draggable is dropped, the CardPiles div height changes according to the divs inside it. What do I do to keep the div height and content posn static?  Note #CardPiles elements are dynamic and can have any number of div elements inside it...

Comment: You can replace the `div`that is dragged away with a stub or placeholder `div`.