# With jquery UI drag and Drop feature, reverting the dropped element based on some condition

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, revert

```
$(function(){
      $(".item").draggable({
        revert:"invalid",
        revertDuration:"900",
        appendTo:'droppable-container'
      });

      $(".droppable-container").droppable({
        drop:function(event,ui){
          ui.draggable.appendTo(this);
        }
      })
    })
```

i just want to revert back the first dropped element after second element is dropped on droppable container,

i,e droppable container can have maximum of one item, if new item is dropped on droppable the the first dropped element must revert back to its parent.

please check the codepen link,[darg and drop with revert on condition](https://codepen.io/kaleem78/pen/rKzwBv)

newly added(dropped)item must remain and the previously added element must revert back to its parent.
and also i want a animation effect when reverting the old/previously dropped item.

thank you...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So the first part of this is storing the original position in the `start` callback. So that later, the item can be returned to that position later if needed. The next part id how do you want to show that it's reverted, an animation? When the item B is dropped, item A is detached and returned to it's original position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691702/jquery-drag-drop-revert-to-original-position-and-div-on-double-click/35711397

Comment: Thank you @Twisty. that link really helped. still i need an animation to show the reverting back. any idea how to achieve that?